# stdio.h - whats the name of libfile and where can I find it Linux

Tags: c, linux, stdio

I have a question about stdio.h in c-language.

well - this contains only the function-prototypes of the standard input- and output-streams.
But there must be a libfile (objectfile) for this standard input- and output, right?

But what is its name and in which folder is it residing in Linux (ubuntu)?

Comment: It's implemented (typically) by libc.

Comment: That would be part of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)! [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) is common for Linux.

Comment: Not sure about Ubuntu, but probably `/lib/libc*` and/or `/lib64/libc*`.

Comment: Note that on Mac OS X, the library is something like `/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)`, as reported by `otool -L /bin/sh` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I compile a simple hello world C program I get this:

```
% ldd easy
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcc9fe000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4a90eb6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4a91299000)
```

Why does it need `libc` ?

```
% nm easy
...
000000000040052d T main
             U printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

The symbol `printf` is being provided by `glibc`. `nm` shows a `printf` symbol is being provided by that object:

```
% nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep printf
...
00000000000542f0 T printf
0000000000109dc0 T __printf_chk
000000000004f1d0 T __printf_fp
```

---

Alternatively you can ask `ldd` to print debugging info:

```
% LD_DEBUG=bindings ./easy 2>&1 | grep printf
    17922:  binding file ./easy [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]:\ 
    normal symbol `printf' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which implementation of the standard library you use, but if you are *mainstream* and compile with gcc you can find the path of an library used to link with

`$ gcc -print-file-name=libc.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`

Take into account that you can have more than one implementation installed in your system.